# Value stored in smart contract changed unexpectedly

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, tron

[image: Smart contract of tron blockchain]

This smart contract is deployed on tron blockchain. It has a variable named "dividendPool". Its value changed unexpectedly. Does anyone faced this strange issue?

Comment: Was this contract deployed on testnet (shasta) ? May be there was a wipe of testnet and unexpected behavior occurred?

Comment: yes, it deployed on the shasta network